Unity is stucked opening a project at "Loading Scripting Assemblies" or "Initial Asset Database Refresh"
The story: I got a new shared Laptop, because my other one was for repair. I have admin/read/write rights, but I couldn't open any project with any version on any drive. No matter if it was an old or a new project. It always got stuck at: "Loading Scripting Assemblies" or "Initial Asset Database Refresh"

Run in CLI one time:
icacls "[Project Path]" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /T

and open projects with:
"[Install Path]\Unity Editor\[Unity Version]\Editor\Unity.exe" -projectPath "[Project Path]" -disableDirectoryMonitor

Unluckily you always have to open the project that way. It is okay for me, because it is an interim solution. If I get a better permanet solution I will give an update.
And at one project a package made a problem. In that case add the "-noupm" argument. Then you can open it and solve the problem and start the project without the "-noupm" argument, after everythings solved.
To avoid the cli, you can add the command " -disableDirectoryMonitor" to the project in the hub.

